# Add rxjs operators to redux store subscription

Tags: redux, rxjs

The redux docs state the store is an observable and you can subscribe to it. Does anyone know how to add operators to store subscriptions such as 'throttle'?

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttle'
```

this works fine:

```
store
  .subscribe(() => saveStateToLocalStorage(store.getState()))
```

this doesn't:

```
store
  .throttle(1000)
  .subscribe(() => saveStateToLocalStorage(store.getState()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, redux store is an observable but it's not based on RxJs.
You can't do that kind of thing natively.

If you're using angular (v2 ou +) with ngrx, your store **is** an observable built on top of RxJs so you might do something like that.

If you're not using ngrx, you should take a look into this **redux-observable** : https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable

Comment: Redux-observable is a good choice if you already know rxjs. Anyway, you need some middleware to do this kind of side effects - more common ones are redux-thunk or redux-saga

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using RxJS 5:

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject().throttle(1000)

subject.subscribe(() => {
  saveStateToLocalStorage(store.getState())
})

store.subscribe(() => {
  subject.next()
})
```